# Async lookup without results hangs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am attempting to use mongoose with async, everything works fine for the most part...however when I perform a lookup that returns no results my application seems to hang and eventually timeout.

Here is some example controller code that does a simple lookup by id using mongoose and async:

```
module.exports.find = function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(next) {
            SomeModel.findById(req.params.id, next);
        },
        function(someModel, next) {
            if (!SomeModel) {
                res.status(404).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'SomeModel not found'
                });
            } else {
                res.json(SomeModel);
            }
        }
    ]);
};
```

If a record is found everything comes back just fine, however for a nonexistent id it seems that the second async step is never called and eventually the whole request times out.

So what am I doing wrong here? How do I get the 'findById' method to call 'next' even if a record isn't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose is throwing an error, and you aren't catching it. The other thing I should mention is that you should be doing your response handling in the final callback (which you have not defined).

Try something like this:

```
module.exports.find = function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(next) {
            SomeModel.findById(req.params.id, next);
        }
    ], function(err, SomeModel){
        // this is the final callback

        if (err) {
            // put error handling here 
            console.log(err)
        }

        if (!SomeModel) {
            res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'SomeModel not found'
            });

        } else {
            res.json(SomeModel);
        }

    });
};
```

Alternatively, you could just simplify it to not use waterfall:

```
module.exports.find = function(req, res) {
    SomeModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, SomeModel){
        if (err) {
            // put error handling here 
            console.log(err)
        }

        if (!SomeModel) {
            res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'SomeModel not found'
            });

        } else {
            res.json(SomeModel);
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer! Thanks for clearing this up for me. For some reason I thought that Async would handle the error for me, isn't that one of the reasons for using it?

Comment: Async assists in some ways as far as error handling goes, but definitely does not handle them completely.